# rewrite url using htaccess for parameters to page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Always confusing with rewrite rules. Can anybody help me on this please.

change parameter to pagename

This is the url from client side.
http://localhost/project/xxx.html

It should access in server like this page.
http://localhost/project/index.php?param1=xxx

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below rule in project directory I am assuming project is directory where you applying the rules,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).html$ index.php?param1=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes. But i place htaccess in folder level. Thanks for your quick response. its working fine.